# alternative to javascript: when & and : is filtered

Tags: javascript, xss

I am trying to learn XSS and I'm stuck on a challenge. I can only do `<a href=x>a</a>` and `x` can be anything except `&` (escaped as &058;) and `:` (colon) so I can't do `&058;`. I can only put something in the `href` field, without quotes or anything like that. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a challenge like this that you're supposed to try to discover the solution on your own?

Comment: Yeah, of course. I've spent about 5 hours on it haha, and none of my friends know the solution (there is no answer key).

Comment: Of the top of my head I can't think of any way, either. But I don't spend much time trying to figure out how to break into computers, I do real programming for a living.

Comment: Is `x` quoted, like `href="x"`? Because if not quoted, as shown in the question, you could put a space and then `onclick=something`.

Comment: As I said, I can only put something in the href, if I do anything else it gets removed. For example if I did <a href=j sgdfgdfg=s>a</a> as the input, the output html would be <a href=j>a</a>. Seems like they have a whitelist

Comment: Well...you said anything except ampersand and colon, and you didn't explain how the value would actually end up in the field so if it was simply output by server-side code like `<a href=<%=x%>>a</a>` then what I mentioned would work. Your phrasing "or anything like that" is a pretty vague requirement.

Comment: I entered that as input, the output was <a href="&lt;%=x%">&gt;a</a> and no I didn't put the quotes

Comment: No, the `<%=x%>` was an example of how server-side code might put a dynamic value into the output string, not an example of something you might try as a value for x. It's an example of server-side code (JSP, in this case) that doesn't guard against XSS. The question itself didn't say what mechanism is used to inject the dynamic x value. What you seem to be saying in comments is that some filtering and HTML entity translation is occurring, but that you don't know what all the rules are for what gets filtered.

Comment: would https://security.stackexchange.com/ be a better place to ask the question?